# MVC DateTime field via DropdownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have to manage a `DateTime` field via a `DropDownList` in order to limit the available date to the user. I build my list of items this way :

```
@{
    var availableDates = Model.GetAvailableDates().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
    {
        Value = x.ToString(),
        Text = x.ToStringContextShortDate()
    });

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.TreatmentDate, availableDates , new { @class = "form-control fullWidth" })
```

My problem is, depending the browser (chrome vs firefox), the client side form validation fails because the browser can't cast the selected value (date.ToString()) to a valid date. Same problem appends on chrome when the server language is different to browser language. I thought I could resolve this by setting the value attribute of my items as a Json date, but still it does not work.

Comment: may want to make this a custom property on your view model.. and just make sure it has a value if it's required.. you're only giving them valid dates so you shouldnt have to validate the date itself

Comment: @JamieD77 might actually be the best solution ....

Comment: A solution that is a bit more complex but might work is using something like https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. This will enable a calendar and allow you to specify dates that the user cannot select from as well as a min/max range. It uses moment.js so you have an actual date time object client side which you can either send to the server or set to a hidden field in a specific format (yyyy-MM-dd example) for a form post. It also allows for localization. Downside to these features: time to implement this is more than a simple drop-down and you will need javascript.

Comment: Format the option values as ISO format - `Value = x.ToString(yyyy-MM-dd),`

Comment: @user3559349 Careful. If you format the value, it won't be able to set the selected value when `x.TreatmentDate` already has one.